# Easiest way in browser to detect mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

I use a script generator -- http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ --  to detect mobile phones in order to redirect the page to a subdomain that has a special template for phones.

I'm only interested in mobile phones only. Ipad, Android tablets will not be redirected. All I need to know is if this script covers IPhone 4 and IPhone 5, because I don't have these models to test it. Anyway, I have tested on Safari using Developer menu - user agent - Safari ios 4.3.3 Iphone, and the page is redirected as needed. Is this enough for what I want or I should use the following script too:

```
var iphone4 = (window.screen.height == (960 / 2)) ? true : false;
var iphone5 = (window.screen.height == (1136 / 2)) ? true : false;
if (iphone4 && iphone5) {
    parent.location.href='http://www.mobile.mysite.com';
}
```

Comment: I would say that screensize is a safer way to do this if you are only interested in screen resolutions. If you have mobile specific features at the subdomain, then this sort of hacky thing is the only method I am aware of.

Comment: I would use Mobile_Detect PHP Class. It has all kinds of options, and can even add your own detection parameters. Source: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: There's more and more overlap in screen sizes between phones and tablets these days.

Comment: I thought the same to, otherwise I would use a simple script like: if( screen.width <= 500) {location.href="reditect.html"}

Comment: Adam D, my site is HTML, so I can't use Mobile_Detect PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the regex from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ will detect iPhone (and iPod Touch for that matter) all versions...`ip(hone|od)` is the regex portion that will match it.

<s>if you wanted a script just for iPhone/iPod you could trim the aforementioned script down to:</s>

```
(function (a, b) { if (/ip(hone|od)/i.test(a)) window.location = b }
)(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://www.mobile.mysite.com');
```

EDIT:

or instead use this script to detect Mobile devices

```
(function (a, b) { if (/Mobi/.test(a)) window.location = b }
)(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://www.mobile.mysite.com');
```

based on the recommendation of [Browser detection using the user agent | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent):

> we recommend looking for the string "Mobi" anywhere in the User Agent to detect a mobile device. If the device is large enough that it's not marked with "Mobi", you should serve your desktop site (which, as a best practice, should support touch input anyway, as more desktop machines are appearing with touchscreens).

Comment: I don't need any script just for iPhone/iPad. All I need is to redirect only the mobile phones users to mobile version site including iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. So you say it's working on those too. Its better to use regex compare with: if( screen.width <= 800)  ?

Comment: see my edit...user agent sniffing for "Mobi" is the recommended method for mobile device detection.  Checking `screen.width` may work as well but is more likely to result in false positives given the variety of screens/devices out there.

Comment: Unfortunately using this script will enable mobile site version for Ipad's which is really bad ( I just test it ), so I'm back to http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ script.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
var bIsMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") == -1);
```

Comment: Use "Mobi" instead of "mobile" as said by MikeM